# Boost Async Threading

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

So I have been using boost as a solution for threading.
I seem to be having an issue where the threads I create dont let the main thread that was executing them continue.
Eg:

```
int main(){
    while(1){
        speech listen; //create speech object
        boost::thread speech_thd(boost::bind(&speech::Run,&listen));
        speech_thd.join();
        std::cout<<"test\n";
        //Some sleep call here 
    }
```

The "test" call is only printed after speech_thd finishes execution.
How would I create it such that I get execution on the main while(1) as well?
If I can do this I will obviously move the thread creation outside the while(1) :P
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this code correct? Is `speech Listen;` and the `&listen` on the next line the same object (is this a typo?), or are they different objects?

Comment: Sorry caps issue. I was just using this as a demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `join` on the thread you just created - `join` specifically waits there in the main thread until the `speech_thd` terminates, see here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html

Comment: Will the thread start execution without a call to join()? Also, will this also work if I call the arg as follows: boost::thread(&listen::RecordMethod,this); ? [Note that this is called within the object Listen itself.

Comment: Yes, the thread starts immediately upon construction. I am not sure about your second question - perhaps you should ask another question on SO.